# Docusign Admin API access

Tags: rest, docusignapi, docusignconnect

We have usecase where we want to get list of accounts for a given email id across organization. We are trying to use [https://demo.docusign.net/Management/v2/organizations/{{organizationId}}/users/profile?email={{email}}](https://demo.docusign.net/Management/v2/organizations/%7B%7BorganizationId%7D%7D/users/profile?email=%7B%7Bemail%7D%7D) API to get the data.

We are always getting some HTML response back.

About Authentication.

We followed the steps mentioned on https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/admin101/application-auth/ to associate the app with Admin with **user_read account_read group_read** accesses. and then used https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/ to generate the assertion and access token.

any inputs will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First off, the list of scopes you want to use should include:

```
 user_read user_write organization_read account_read group_read permission_read identity_provider_read domain_read
```

Second, with JWT you may want to check the impersonated user you're using, to ensure that is an admin, and not just an account admin, but an organization admin.

Third, make sure the orgId in your URL is correct.